# Changing permalinks structure without loosing SEO

Tags: permalinks, seo

Current structure is `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html`

Desired structure is `/%postname%/`

Since we are already positioned with urls like `domain.com/2015/04/example-post.html`, we want people to be redirected to `domain.com/example-post/`.

I already tried installing some plugins, like **Simple 301 Redirects**, which looked good since it seems to work with rules as shown in the image below:

[image]

But it didn't worked to us, we get 404 from old urls :(

Adding 301 rules manually is not an options since we have thousands of posts, doing it with a script would be a easy option but I don't think is optimal to have thousands of 301 rules, would it be?

Any other suggestion?

Comment: You can not use the wordpress variables in there. You can use regex but the option below would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a plugin to achieve your goal. Use server redirect in the `.htaccess` file because it will not load the processor to interpret the WordPress PHP code and will not consume time. The redirect will be completed before the WordPress runs.

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where

- `[0-9]+/` is the numeric year and month
- `(.*)` is the part we'll use below (`example-post` in your case)
- `/$1` is the part we've got from the above

301 redirect is completely perfect for SEO.

Comment: I already got it working with other similar rule, but thanks for your explanation, nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

This tool did the work for me: https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php

there you enter the old and new permalinks structure and it gives a single rule, in mi case:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$ https://domain.com/$3
```